# Reflect a letter horizontally using CSS

Tags: css, css-transforms

I know how to reflect single letters vertically using `transform: rotate();` but not how to reflect them horizontally.

Do you know how I can reflect them horizontally?

I want to use it with the selector `.logo:first-letter {}` for my logo.

```
<a href="#" class="logo">RR</a>
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/n7YA7/1/

Cant use Я because I'm using a font from google which doesn't support it.

Comment: Same here. The code Matt Bryant gave me works, but not with first-letter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `scaleX` property as a transform.

```
.logo:first-letter {
     transform: scaleX(-1);
 }
```

If it's always a specific letter, it might be a better idea to just use unicode for this.  In your case, [`CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER YA`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/42f/index.htm) (Я) will work.

Comment: Thanks for the qiuck anwer. I got your point. The problem is Im using @font-face with another font from google. This font doesnt support this letter. Thats why I have to reflect it.

Comment: Yeah, I realize this.  Does it need to be an `<a>`?   What if you use a span instead but set the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Im kinda confused. No matter what element or wish selector I use, it wont work. :O

Comment: @RobertRichter: Like I said in my comment earlier (which I deleted) `::first-letter` only works on elements that are `inline-block` or `block` by default - using a `<p>` instead allows it work: http://jsfiddle.net/n7YA7/3/

Answer (score 0):

I would use scale:

```
transform:scale(-1, 1);
-ms-transform:scale(-1, 1); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:scale(-1, 1); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

Check here if it is right for you: http://jsfiddle.net/kytXf/